# What does an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think this is a basic idea, but I am not understanding ...

I know an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ has the form $f(x)+\langle x^2+1\rangle$ for some $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$. Furthermore this can be simpilfied to $f(x)+g(x)(x^2+1)$ for some $g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$. What I do not understand is why it it is guaranteed that $f(x)$ is linear. Can anyone please clarify this fact?

Grazie mille!

Comment: That is what my books says, but it still does not make sense to me. What about $f(x)$?

Comment: If $f(x)$ contains $3x^2$, you subtract $3(x^2+1)$ from $f(x)$ and add $3$ to $g(x)$.  If $f(x)$ contains $2x^3$, you subtract $2x(x^2+1)$ from $f(x)$ and add $2x$ to $g(x)$.

Comment: Maybe I should leave $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ as it is. Let me see if this makes more sense. An element looks like $f(x)+\langle x^2+1\rangle$. By the Division Algorithm this is equal to $q(x)(x^2+1)+r(x)+\langle x^2+1\rangle$. However the degree of $r(x)<2$ and $q(x)(x^2+1)$ is absorbed by $\langle x^2+1\rangle$. This means an element looks like $ax+b+\langle x^2+1\rangle$. Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: YAY ME! Thank you so much ... now that I actually UNDERSTAND what is being asked I can attempt to actually prove it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's guaranteed that $f(x)$ is linear (or constant) because if $f(x)$ is not linear, then the division algorithm says you can write $f(x) = q(x)(x^2+1) + r(x)$ for some polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$, where $r(x)$ is identically zero or $\deg r(x) < \deg (x^2 + 1)$.

Well, since $\deg (x^2 + 1) = 2$ then this means $\deg r(x) = 1$ (linear) or $\deg r(x) = 0$ (constant).  So $r(x)$ is linear or constant.  And since $x^2 + 1$ "equals" zero in $\Bbb{Z}_{11}[x]/ \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$, then $q(x)(x^2 + 1)$ is zero.  This means $f(x)$ and $r(x)$ belong to the same equivalence class, and since $r(x)$ is linear or constant, then for all intents and purposes we can regard $f(x)$ as linear or constant.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use the division algorithm, you may find it clearer to reason *equationally* using congruences in the quotient ring, where $x^2+1\equiv 0\,$ therefore $\,\color{#c00}{x^2\equiv -1}$. We can use this congruence as a rewrite rule to reduce all exponents on $x$ till they are smaller than $2$.

Every power of $x$ has form $x^{2n+i}$ for $i\in \{0,1\}\,$ so $\, x^{2n+i}\equiv (\color{#c00}{x^2})^n x^i \equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^n x^i$

Since $\,i < 2\,$ this shows how to reduce all exponents on $x$ to be $< 2,\,$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is a field, you can do euclidean division and write every $g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$ as $g(x)=q(x)(x^2+1)+r(x)$ where $r(x)$ is linear (and unique).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a polynomial $g(x) = a_nx^n + ... + a_0$. Then we can drop its degree by taking
$$g(x) - 0 = g(x) - x^{n-2}(x^2 + 1) = a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + (a_{n-2} - 1)x^{n-2} + ... + a_0$$

because $x^{n-2}(x^2+1) = x^{n-2}(0) = 0$ in the factor ring. By repeating this, it's possible to get rid of any term $cx^i$ where $i\geq 2$.

Comment: This is a bit clearer when done *equationally* - see my answer.